# Pager for parent node in drupal

Tags: drupal

How I make pager for parent node not for child node.Is any module in drupal for providing      full pager for same content type by making parent node and child node?

Comment: I want to make pager for some content.And content is belong to same content type.but I have to show some nodes not all nodes.Thats why i make parent node.So that pager only show on only some node.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not clear to me what you want to achieve. Probably you want to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. You can find documentation and tutorials on [this page](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views). It's very powerful tool but using it requires some practice.